# Uncaught Error: Class &quot;Google\ApiCore\Serializer&quot; not found in test/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php:93

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm having troubles with importing my firestore.

I have created `Firestore.php` that connects to the Database and contains the functions.
However Everytime that I want to use something it throws me this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class &quot;Google\ApiCore\Serializer&quot; not found in /public_html/sendimgs/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/sendimgs/vendor/google/cloud-firestore/Connection/Grpc.php(81): Google\Cloud\Core\GrpcRequestWrapper-&gt;__construct(Array)
#1 /public_html/sendimgs/vendor/google/cloud-firestore/FirestoreClient.php(111): Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc-&gt;__construct(Array)
#2 /public_html/sendimgs/Firestore.php(14): Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient-&gt;__construct(Array)
#3 /public_html/sendimgs/index.php(19): Firestore-&gt;__construct()
#4 {main}
  thrown in <b>/sendimgs/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
```

### `Firestore.php`

```
<?php

use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\CollectionReference;

class Firestore
{
    private FirestoreClient $firestore;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->firestore = new FirestoreClient([
            ...
        ]);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->firestore->...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I saw that my GRPC was not working because GCC version was old, I done an upgrade in gcc from version 4.5 to 7.3, done reinstall of GRPC
After this I upgraded composer packages:

> "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.25",
>
> "google/apiclient": "^2.12",
>
> "grpc/grpc": "^1.42",
>
> "google/protobuf": "^3.21"

Comment: Can you provide more information about GCC. I can't find how to upgrade GCC on windows.

Comment: I used a server linux in cloud. I don't have idea how GCC works on Windows.